# What hash algorithm is being used by @Password formula?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Does anyone know what hash algorithm is being used by @Password formula? My client keeps user accounts in standalone LDAP server. They need to sync passwords from LDAP to Domino internet password in person documents. We are trying to find a way how to accomplish this having only hashed version of password in LDAP. If Domino @Password would use some known hash algorythm like MD5, SHA etc. we can store password in LDAP this way and simply replace it in person documents.

Any idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link is the public details on the Encryption methods in Domino.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_NOTES_AND_DOMINO_ENCRYPTION_2250_OVER.html

Depending on how you have your server set up, using @Password may not work. The administrator can set "Use more secure Internet passwords" option.

This generates a personalised salt for each user in the $SecurePassword field of the person document (the field is protected as well). To correctly hash the password in this instance you need to use [@Hashpassword](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_HASHPASSWORD.html). If the administrator knows what they are doing then the related password fields will be locked down by the xACL to prevent external access (for security reasons).

It is a little unclear what you are trying to achieve though. You can use [Directory Assistance](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_ABOUT_DIRECTORY_ASSISTANCE.html) in Domino to authenticate against a third party LDAP.

Comment: If I recall correctly, even the old unsalted password storage (which I would never recommend using!) was a slightly modified version of MD2.  So even without the "more secure Internet password option", I think the idea of copying a hash from any other system's standard algorithm is out of the question. They could never match.